# Event not firing for dojo's DataGrid

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I have a DataGrid connected to a certain store. I want it to save as soon as a change is made.

There is only one editable column which has a 3-option dropdown set to always editing defined like this:

```
                <table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" id="leaveGrid" data-dojo-id="leaveGrid"
                     selectable=false singleClickEdit="true">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th field="TITLE" width="25%">Title</th>
                        <th field="REQUESTEDON" width="15%">Requested</th>
                        <th field="CODE" width="15%">Code</th>
                        <th field="LEAVEDATE" width="15%">Leave Date</th>
                        <th field="HRS" width="15%">Hours</th>
                        <th field="STATUS" width="15%" editable="true" alwaysEditing="true" cellType="dojox.grid.cells.Select" options='<?php echo $this->statusOptions;?>'>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

The options for the dropdown are populated by php but that shouldn't be a problem.

I make the following connection:

```
dojo.connect(gridStore, 'onSet', saveStore);
```

Which handles the saving of the store.

Now the problem is that I click on the dropdown, change the option and... nothing happens. No event fires unless I hit enter or click elsewhere on the screen (changing focus or selection if you will); only then does the event fire.

Is there a different event I should be using? What can I do to make this data be saved as soon as the user changes it and without further interaction?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do here:

1) Use onClick instead of onSet

2) Use onApplyCellEdit event which requires Enter key or blur. You can display a tooltip to user on how to use inline editing

3) Inspect the html generated by grid and attach handler to the select drop down's id/class/name